# Method types incompatiblity

Tags: streaming, ocaml

I tried recently play with a streaming liquidsoap-like stuff... There's some code which uses OCaml classes and C libraries for encoding like lame (via ocaml-lame) etc.

```
(* Lame module *)
type encoder
(* ... *)
external encode_buffer_float_part : encoder -> float array -> float array -> int -> int -> string = "ocaml_lame_encode_buffer_float"

(* Otherencoder module *)
type encoder
(* ... *)
external encode_buffer_float_part : encoder -> float array -> float array -> int -> int -> string = "ocaml_otherencoder_encode_buffer_float"
```

(=same interface)

Somewhere there's a two high-level classes that inherit from two separated `encoderbase` virtual classes:

```
(* Mp3_output module *)
class virtual encoderbase =
    object (self)
    method encode ncoder channels buf offset size =
        if channels = 1 then
            Lame.encode_buffer_float_part ncoder buf.(0) buf.(0) offset size
        else
            Lame.encode_buffer_float_part ncoder buf.(0) buf.(1) offset size
end

(* somewhere in the code *)
class to_shout sprop =
    (* some let-s *)
    object (self)
    inherit
        [Lame.encoder] Icecast2.output ~format:Format_mp3 (* more params *) as super
    inherit base
    (* ... *)
end
```

and

```
(* Other_output module *)
class virtual encoderbase =
    object (self)
    method encode ncoder channels buf offset size =
        if channels = 1 then
            Otherencoder.encode_buffer_float_part ncoder buf.(0) buf.(0) offset size
        else
            Otherencoder.encode_buffer_float_part ncoder buf.(0) buf.(1) offset size
end

(* somewhere in the code *)
class to_shout sprop =
    (* some let-s *)
    object (self)
    inherit
        [Otherencoder.encoder] Icecast2.output ~format:Format_other (* more params *) as super
    inherit base
    (* ... *)
end
```

All things work fine with:

```
let icecast_out source format =
    let sprop =
        new Mp3_output.shout_sprop
    in
        (* some code here *)
        new Mp3_output.to_shout sprop
```

but when I try something like this:

```
let icecast_out source format =
    let sprop =
        if format = Format_other then
            new Other_output.shout_sprop
        else
            new Mp3_output.shout_sprop
    in
        (* some code here *)
        if format = Format_mp3 then
            new Mp3_output.to_shout sprop
        else
            new Other_output.to_shout sprop
```

compilation breaks with an error @ `new Other_output.to_shout sprop`:

```
Error: This expression has type Other_output.to_shout
    but an expression was expected of type Mp3_output.to_shout
    Types for method encode are incompatible
```

Is there any way to "convince" OCaml (common ancestor? wrapping class? type casting?) to compile with that two different classes/bindings at once?

Update (2015.12.15):
Code sample: https://gist.github.com/soutys/22b67a5df9ae0a6f1f72

Comment: can you please include a full error message?

Comment: I don't see any C involved in your problem ...

Comment: @JensGustedt they are the function definitions prefixed with `external` that are calls to C.

Comment: I removed tag C from the list, since indeed the question is about type system and OCaml. The fact, that external functions is called doesn't affect the type system at all.

Comment: Are you sure the two interfaces at the start are the same? It looks like the first requires a `Lame.encoder` argument, while the second needs an `Otherencoder.encoder`. i.e. they are not interchangeable, and so the two methods won't be either. You should probably move the `ncoder` method argument to the constructor to make the interfaces the same.

Comment: @ThomasLeonard is right. Your two types named `encoder` are completely different (abstract) types. So your two classes `shout_sprop` have completely different class types (though you don't show them). Most likely you need to make the encoder an internal detail of your `Lame` and `Otherencoder` modules. Maybe you don't need to expose the encoder type at all?.

Comment: @ThomasLeonard i've added passing "type as a value" (?) through constructors (?) but with no luck. Gist added...

Comment: @JeffreyScofield encoder type is a mandatory parameter for ocaml-lame (https://github.com/savonet/ocaml-lame), ocaml-vorbis (https://github.com/savonet/ocaml-vorbis) and so on...  

There's something I don't understand in OCaml :) (and it's beyond run-time vs compile-time typing)... I'm just starting here...

Comment: I'm not sure how many encoders you have at a time. If you have many, you can have `Lame` and `Otherencoder` be classes rather than modules. Each instance could perhaps have an encoder inside it (as an internal detail). If you only have one of each, you can maybe just keep the encoder inside the module. Then you don't have to expose it (outside the module). You would use it when doing encoding, naturally. The key is to hide what doesn't matter to callers. Callers (I would assume) just care about their arrays of float.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to "convince" OCaml (common ancestor? wrapping class? type casting?) to compile with that two different classes/bindings at once?

It is believed that OCaml is a type safe language, so it is not possible to convince OCaml to compile a program that will crash, unless you're using some sinister methods.

The root of your misunderstanding is illustrated by the following code snippet from your example:

```
type 'a term = Save of 'a
let enc_t =
  if format_num = 1
  then Save Lame.encoder
  else Save Other.encoder
```

An expression `Save Lame.encoder` has a type `Lame.encoder term`, while an expression `Save Other.encoder` has a type `Other.encoder term`. From a type system perspective this are two completly different types, albeit they were built by the same type constructor `term`. C.f., `int list` and `float list` are different types, and you can't assign to the same variable values of this two different types. That is not a property of OCaml per se, this is a property of any parametric polymorphism, e.g.,  `std::vector<int>` and `std::vector<float>` are different types with different representation and their values can't be used interchangeably, although strictly speaking templates in c++ are not true parametric polymorphism, they are just macro.

But back to OCaml. The idea behind the polymorphic function is that a parameter which has a polymorphic data type has the same representation, and function can be applied to any instance of this type without any runtime check, since all type information is removed. For example,

```
let rec length = function
  | [] -> 0
  | _ :: xs -> 1 + length xs
```

is polymorphic because it can be applied to any instance of polymorphic data type `'a list`, including `int list`, `float list`, `person list`, etc.

On the other hand, a function

```
let rec sum = function 
  | [] -> 0
  | x :: xs -> x + sum xs
```

is not polymorphic and can be applied only to values of type `int list`. The reason is because the implementation of this function relies on a fact, that every element is an integer. If you will be able to convince the type system, to apply this function to `float` list, you will get a segmentation fault.

But you may say, that we miss something, as a sum function for `float` list looks basically the same:

```
let rec fsum = function 
  | [] -> 0.
  | x :: xs -> x +. fsum xs
```

So there is an opportunity to abstract a summation. When we abstract something we find the things that differ between different implementations and *abstract* them out. The simplest abstraction primitive in OCaml is a function, so lets do it:

```
let rec gsum zero plus xs =
  let (+) = plus in
  let rec sum = function
    | [] -> zero
    | x :: xs -> x + sum xs in
  sum xs
```

We abstracted out the `zero` element and a `plus` function. So that we get an abstraction of summation, that works for any type for which you can provide a `plus` operation and element neutral to this opperation (called a Ring data stucture in abstract algebra). The type of the gsum is

```
'a -> ('b -> 'a -> 'a) -> 'b list -> 'a
```

It is even too generic, and we can specialize it a little bit, as this type

```
'a -> ('a -> 'a -> 'a) -> 'a list -> 'a
```

suits better. Instead of passing elements of the ring structure one by one, we can aggregate it into a record type:

```
type 'a ring = {
    zero : 'a;
    plus : 'a -> 'a -> 'a
}
```

and implement our generic `sum` as follows:

```
let rec gsum ring xs =
  let (+) = ring.plus in
  let rec sum = function
    | [] -> ring.zero
    | x :: xs -> x + sum xs in
  sum xs
```

In that case we will have a nice type `sum : 'a ring -> 'a list -> 'a`. At some point of time, you will find yourself extending this record with new fields, and implementing more and more functions, that accepts this ring structure as a first parameter. And this would be a good time to use a more heavy abstraction, called `functor`. The `functor` is actually a record on steroids, that is implicitly passed to each function of the functor implementation. Other then functions, records of functions and functors there're other abstraction techniques: first-class modules, objects, classes and, soon, implicits (aka type classes). It is a part of the programming expertise to learn how to choose an abstraction technique that suits better in each particular case. The general advice would be to use least heavy one if possible. And indeed in 95% using functions or records of functions is enough.

Now let's go back to your example. Here you're hitting in the same hole, 
you're confusing polymorpism with abstraction:

```
let fmt =
  if format_num = 1
  then new Lamefmt.sout sp
  else new Otherfmt.sout sp in
```

`Lamefmt.sout` and `Otherfmt.sout` are different types, the first one has type:

```
type sout = <
  doenc  : Lame.encoder -> float array array -> int -> int -> string;
  encode : Lame.encoder -> float array array -> int -> int -> string 
>
```

and the second:

```
type sout = < 
  doenc  : Other.encoder -> float array array -> int -> int -> string;
  encode : Other.encoder -> float array array -> int -> int -> string 
>
```

This are two different objects, although they have resembling scheme, and that means that we have some abstraction opportunity here.

In your case we can start with a simple observation, that both encoder functions has the same type modulo the encoder object itself. Using Occam's razor principle, we're trying to catch this with the simplest abstraction possible -- a function:

```
type encoder = buffer -> buffer -> int -> int -> string
```

where

```
type buffer = float array array
```

Then we can construct different encoders:

```
let lame : encoder = 
   let encoder = Lame.create_encoder () in
   Lame.encode_buffer_float_part encoder

let other : encoder = 
   let encoder = Other.create_encoder () in 
   Other.encode_buffer_float_part encoder
```

And then you can use this two values interchangaebly. Sometimes, different encoders will require different parameters, in that case our task is to dispatch them as soon as possible, e.g.,

```
 let very_customizable_encoder x y z : encoder = 
   let encoder = VCE.create_encoder x y z in 
   Other.encode_buffer_float_part encoder
```

In that case, you should resolve the customization issue as close to user  as possible, and later work with the abstraction.

It is quite often to use hashtables or other associative data structures to store encoders. Such approach will even allow you to represent a plugin architecture, where plugins are loaded dynamically and register themselves (the value of type encoder) in some table.

Conclusion. It is enough to use a function to represent your problem. Maybe at some point of time you will need to use records of functions. So far I don't see the need for using classes. Usually, they are required when you're interested in open recursion, i.e., when your problem is represented by a set of mutual recursive functions, and you want to leave some of the functions unspecified, i.e., to parametrize the implementation.

Comment: Amazing, always quality from @ivg.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing is to simplify your example. e.g. removing irrelevant bits and adding dummy stubs so we don't need real encoders:

```
module Lame = struct
  type encoder
  let encode_buffer_float_part : encoder -> float -> unit = fun _ -> failwith "ocaml_lame_encode_buffer_float"
end

module Otherencoder = struct
  type encoder
  let encode_buffer_float_part : encoder -> float -> unit = fun _ -> failwith "ocaml_otherencoder_encode_buffer_float"
end

module Mp3_output = struct
  class to_shout = object
    method encode ncoder x =
      Lame.encode_buffer_float_part ncoder x
  end
end

module Other_output = struct
  class to_shout = object
    method encode ncoder x =
      Otherencoder.encode_buffer_float_part ncoder x
  end
end

type format = Format_other | Format_mp3

let icecast_out source format =
  if format = Format_mp3 then new Mp3_output.to_shout
  else new Other_output.to_shout
```

gives

```
Error: This expression has type Other_output.to_shout
       but an expression was expected of type Mp3_output.to_shout
       Types for method encode are incompatible
```

Which is correct. If I give you "a value returned by `icecast_out`" then you wouldn't know how to call it, because you wouldn't know what the first argument should be.

Since the encoder is different for each class, it should probably be a constructor argument. e.g.

```
module Mp3_output = struct
  class to_shout ncoder = object
    method encode x =
      Lame.encode_buffer_float_part ncoder x
  end
end

module Other_output = struct
  class to_shout ncoder = object
    method encode x =
      Otherencoder.encode_buffer_float_part ncoder x
  end
end

type format = Format_other | Format_mp3

let icecast_out source format =
  if format = Format_mp3 then new Mp3_output.to_shout Lame.ncoder
  else new Other_output.to_shout Otherencoder.ncoder
```